# Using windows environment variables in eclipse preferences

Tags: eclipse, variables, dropbox, environment, texlipse

I use eclipse (texlipse) on several computers, using Dropbox.
In each computer, the dropbox folder absolute path is different.
I would like to point eclipse's (texlipse's) spell-checker dictionary to a file that is in my dropbox directory.
In order for this to work in all computers, I wanted to define an environment variable that points to my dropbox folder.
However, eclipse doesn't recognize windows's environment variables in its properties.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have an environment variable *DICTIONARY_HOME* containing path to your local dropbox folder. And let's assume you have a *user_dictionary.txt* file there.
Setting `${env_var:DICTIONARY_HOME}/user_dictionary.txt` into *User defined dictionary* of *General* > *Editors* > *Text Editors* > *Spelling* in the preferences solves the problem!

Works at eclipse 4.3.0 @ win7 x64

Comment: Thanks!Note, however, that this works only for eclipse's dictionary, but not for texlipse's dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - missed TeXlipse having its own spellchecker (